# Updating a row in a table while selecting another row from another table to show where to update

Tags: php, sql, select, sql-update, where-clause

I have the tables:

```
__ Members __
ID(int) auto_increment
Email varchar(255) not null

__Options__
ID(int) auto_increment
FORMATION(int) not null
```

And I need to build a SQL request where I can update the row `Options.Formation = 1` where my row `Options.ID = Members.ID` using the `Email` to identify which user is selected.

Does anyone have a clue?
I searched on internet but nothing wants to work... :(

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Sample data and desired results would help.  (3) There is no connection between `options` and `members`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a `member_id` in the `options` table, then I *think* you want:

```
update options
    set formation = 1
    where member_id in (select m.id from members m where m.email = ?);
```

If multiple members can have the same email, then use `in` rather than `=`.

Comment: Solved it ! Thank you so much !
I will mark your reply as the answer as soon as i can ! :)